# Apache - Uploading a file freezes my website

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, debian

I have an Apache server running a PHP website.

When I am uploading a file or downloading a file from/to my server via the website, my whole website cannot respond to any other queries the time the download finishes.

It looks like my Apache has only 1 thread and cannot serve any other queries while my download is not finished.

My server has Debian, on a Pentium4 3Ghz CPU with 1Go RAM.

**Question**

How can I fix this issue so I can serve queries while Apache uploads or downloads a file to another client?

Comment: You must be doing something strange, Does your website freeze? OR your browser freezes?. Run this test: Open Firefox > start download/upload, while that is happening, open Chrome/IE access your website. If it opens, there is a good probablity that its not APACHE

Comment: The website does not respond. The browser is all right. Apache is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried directly accessing an image or some non-PHP resource on the server? I doubt Apache would freeze from a file upload, but PHP scripts might.

If you've configured PHP to auto-start sessions, the default file-based session handler locks the session file for the lifetime of the script, which means your upload will lock out all other PHP scripts for the duration of the upload.

So, try directly hitting an image, or some text, etc... something that isn't PHP and see if the server responds. If it does, then it's your PHP configuration, and the session handler is the most likely culprit.

Comment: I think you got it. Indeed only PHP based uploads are freezing my session. And then all PHP scripts using session_start() does not respond. What can I do to prevent this issue?

Comment: Disable the auto-start sessions for the upload script. You should be able to do that via a `<Files upload.php> php_value session.auto_start = 0</Files>` or whatever in Apache. Anything else in PHP that's long-running, put a `session_write_close()` before the long-running section. You'll still be able to access the session data, but any changes won't be written out. If need be, you can always do a session_start() again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#keepalive
and providing the right settings for Your apache server...